# angularjs clear backing field when input box hides

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I have a page that will hide/show additional elements when an option is selected:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        opt: <select ng-model="model.opt" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in model.opts"></select>
        <br/> <span ng-show="model.opt > 1">
        alt: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.alt"  />
        </span>

        <div> <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7wsdj74/

How would I setup to get notification when the "ng-hide" is evaluated so that the model fields being hidden can be set back to some default values (in this case null)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is reset the model on changes:

```
<select ng-model="..." ng-options="..." ng-change="model.alt = null"></select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfrola/wzpha8c3/

You can also define a more complex reset function and use `ng-change="reset()"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll probably go with the reset function as it can be more flexible in other field contexts and what exactly changed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
scope.$watch('myParameter', (value) => {
    // if myParameter is false set it to null?
 }
```

Comment: I'll probably end up falling back on something like this or perhaps massaging the data before acting on it.